# WPF FlowDocumentScrollViewer Selection.Select Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to select text in my FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

I am able to find the TextPointer start position and end position.  So I have 2 TextPointers...

```
TextPointer startPos;
TextPointer endPos;
```

Using these 2 TextPointers I am trying to select text in my FlowDocumentScrollViewer.  I am doing it like this...

```
flowDocumentScrollViewer.Selection.Select(startPos, endPos);
```

I would expect this to highlight the selected text.  But it is not doing this.

Why is this not working???

[UPDATE]
This is how I am getting the TextPointers:

```
TextPointer pointer = flowDocument.Document.ContentStart;
while (pointer != null)
{
  if (pointer.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
  {
    string textRun = pointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    // where textRun is the text in the flowDocument
    // and searchText is the text that is being searched for
    int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(searchText);
    if (indexInRun >= 0)
    {
      TextPointer startPos = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
      TextPointer endPos = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun + searchText.Length);
    }
  }
  pointer = pointer.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied the following code from the MSDN documentation of the [TextRange.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.select.aspx) method, replaced the RichTextBox with a FlowDocumentScrollViewer and it works as expected. How did you define your TextPointers? That *seems* to be the most probable cause of your problem.

UPDATE: I updated my code to include your selection algorithm and it still works. The only thing I'm aware of doing different is the "break" after selecting. Otherwise it'd select from the beginning of the first occurence of searchText until after the end of the last occurence. Other than that I could imagine that your searchText might not be included in your document at all (perhaps a casing issue?), but that's just guessing. Did you debug your code? Are the TextPointers valid (not null etc.) when you try to select the text?

XAML:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer GotMouseCapture="richTB_GotMouseCapture" Name="richTB">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph Name="myParagraph">
            <Run>
                When the user clicks in the RichTextBox, the selected text changes programmatically.
            </Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
private void richTB_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = "text";
    TextPointer pointer = richTB.Document.ContentStart;
    while (pointer != null)
    {
        if (pointer.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            string textRun = pointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            // where textRun is the text in the flowDocument
            // and searchText is the text that is being searched for
            int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(searchText);
            if (indexInRun >= 0)
            {
                TextPointer startPos = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
                TextPointer endPos = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun + searchText.Length);
                richTB.Selection.Select(startPos, endPos);
                break;
            }
        }
        pointer = pointer.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  See my edit above.  Do you see anything problematic with that code?

Comment: Updated my answer to include your selection algorithm.

Comment: Actually I do have the "break" in the same spot you do.  The text that I am searching for is indeed included in the document.  When I debug it finds the search text and creates TextPointers that are not null.  The only difference I really see is that you are executing the code from an GotMouseCapture event.  My event is being fired from another user control.  But I don't see why that would be a problem as long as I can get a reference to the FlowDocumentScrollViewer correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that wouldn't make a difference - I'm just using this event because the MSDN example I initially copied does. Actually I don't really know how to help you besides reviewing a more complete reproduction of your problem. Do you think you can produce a small project that does this?

Comment: I noticed something new while debugging.  When I run the Selection.Select(startPos, endPos) command it returns a message that says "Expression has been evaluated and has no value."  I don't understand this message???

Comment: That just means that Select(..) returns nothing (it has a return type of void).

Comment: Ok so i moved the code around a little bit (because I am using MVVM framework).  When I run the command to select the text the selection changes.  It just isn't getting highlighted on the GUI.  Why wouldn't it be getting highlighted?

Comment: I really can't tell without seeing more. Could you extract a small project that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Yes I will do that.  Where can I upload it to so that you can find it?

Comment: If you add a link to it to your question any place should be fine.

Comment: Ok.  I will try to do that today sometime.